# Modal doesn't open when php variables value is large

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, modal-dialog

I am using an edit button inside while loop for each row of table to pass a row values into a modal form.

```
<td><a class="custom-links" onclick='EditModal("<?php echo $data['id']; ?>","<?php echo $data['name']; ?>","<?php echo $data['price']; ?>","<?php echo $data['description']; ?>","<?php echo $data['type']; ?>","<?php echo $data['cooking_instructions']; ?>","<?php echo $data['ingredients']; ?>","<?php echo $data['allergen_warnings']; ?>","<?php echo $data['storage_instructions']; ?>","<?php echo $data['case_size']; ?>","<?php echo 'uploaded_images/'.$data['image']; ?>")'>
    <button type="button" id="<?php echo $data['id']; ?>" class='btn btn-primary glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></button></a></td>
```

Then i set values like

```
function EditModal(id,name,price,description,type,cooking_instructions,ingredients,allergen_warnings,storage_instructions,case_size,image){

document.getElementById("update_id").value = id;
document.getElementById("update_name").value = name;
document.getElementById("update_price").value = price;
document.getElementById("update_description").value = description;
document.getElementById("update_type").value = type;
document.getElementById("update_cooking_instructions").value = cooking_instructions;
document.getElementById("update_ingredients").value = ingredients;
document.getElementById("update_allergen_warnings").value = allergen_warnings;
document.getElementById("update_storage_instructions").value = storage_instructions;
document.getElementById("update_case_size").value = case_size;
document.getElementById("update_image_to_upload").src = image;

$('#update_menu_modal').modal('show');}
```

update_cooking_instructions, update_ingredients, update_allergen_warnings are textareas.

The problem is that modal gets opened when `$data['cooking_instructions'], $data['ingredients'], $data['allergen_warnings']` contain less words or I remove them from `EditModal` function and when their values are large modal does not open.

Can anyone point out my mistake? What am I doing wrong? Modal is opening when I remove these three variables from `EditModal`

Comment: Do you mean to say that `update_cooking_instructions`, `update_ingredients`, and `update_allergen_warnings` are `textareas`?

Comment: Are there any errors in the console in the browser?

Comment: Do the large values include any quotes or newlines?

Comment: yes... update_cooking_instructions, update_ingredients, and update_allergen_warnings are textareas and i am setting their values by javascript function

Comment: Please go ahead and edit the question to fix that sentence, then.

Comment: Their values are long texts and I dont know why their values are not getting passed to EditModal

Comment: Are you going to answer my other questions?

Comment: I have fixed it mate and there are no errors in console

Comment: Yes large values can have quotes and new lines.

Comment: Do you see why quotes and newlines would be a problem? They would make your JavaScript invalid.

Comment: Of course, they would also cause errors in the browser console.

Comment: What are your suggestions about it?

Comment: There are no errors just modal is not opening when EditModal contains these values as source parameters.

Comment: What browser are you using and how are you checking for errors? (I honestly don't believe that there aren't errors.)

Comment: I am using mozilla firefox and checked for errors by F12 key in console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try, though **note that you'll still have a problem with single quotes**:

```
<td><a class="custom-links" onclick='EditModal(<?php echo json_encode($data['id']); ?>,<?php echo json_encode($data['name']); ?>,<?php echo json_encode($data['price']); ?>,<?php echo json_encode($data['description']); ?>,<?php echo json_encode($data['type']); ?>,<?php echo json_encode($data['cooking_instructions']); ?>,<?php echo json_encode($data['ingredients']); ?>,<?php echo json_encode($data['allergen_warnings']); ?>,<?php echo json_encode($data['storage_instructions']); ?>,<?php echo json_encode($data['case_size']); ?>,<?php echo json_encode('uploaded_images/'.$data['image']); ?>)'>
    <button type="button" id=<?php echo json_encode($data['id']); ?> class='btn btn-primary glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></button></a></td>
```

I've removed the double quotes and instead used `json_encode` to emit a value. (I'm making the assumption that each value is a string on the PHP side.)

My guess as to the issue (though I'm stumped as to why it doesn't cause a console error) is that your "large" values have quotes or newlines in them. This sort of thing:

```
EditModal("<?php echo foo; ?>");
```

will turn into this if you have a newline:

```
EditModal("first line
second line");
```

which is not valid JavaScript. Similarly, a double quote would do this:

```
EditModal("Here is a quote --> " <-- see?");
```

which is also not valid JavaScript.

Using this instead:

```
EditModal(<?php echo json_encode(foo); ?>);
```

will turn those examples into these:

```
EditModal("first line\nsecond line");
```

and

```
EditModal("Here is a quote --> \" <-- see?");
```

both of which are fine.

Comment: Try a value with a single quote. Things will still break.